# Can't install KDE app from Discover on my Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 22.04, discover-software-center

I need to install [Kalendar](https://apps.kde.org/kalendar/) on my Kubuntu 22.04, but Discover can't find it. I tried searching in Discover and got infinite loading, tried opening using `plasma-discover --application appstream://org.kde.kalendar` and got something like `Application can't be found in any repo and can't be open`. I don't want to build the app from sources.
Why can't I install KDE apps from Discover? Maybe should I add some URL anywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Kalendar in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402176/how-do-i-install-kalendar-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: See my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1443537/124466